# Need a query to get a single value from comma seperated value in database using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have these in database

```
1      2        3
-------------------
1,2   2,3,4  1,2,3
```

select 1 from table_name where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("value","columnname") > 0
```

Comment: Is there Any Possible to use LIKE operator to find a value ??